# mysql unix_timestamp timezone wrong time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, unix-timestamp

having a problem with UNIX_TIMESTAMP function in mysql.

**The setup:**
I am doing a wordpress site on my local windows machine and upload my updates to an ubuntu server(page.ly) periodically. There is a piece of code that retrieves a datetime column from a mysql db. The problem is the time retrieved is right on my local windows machine, but wrong on the ubuntu server.

**What i know so far**
I ran several queries on both places to try to reproduce the problem.

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-27 22:15:00') 
FROM {$wpdb->posts}"))
```

this produces the right time my local machine(**1343427300**), but wrong on ubuntu(**1343445300** 5 hours ahead. my local timezone America/New_York.).

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-27 22:15:00')"))
```

this produces the right time on both machines. it's like as soon as i associate my select with a table, any table in the database, the time gets the timezone offset + daylight savings offset. i checked the timezone offset on both machines. both of them are 0. im kinda stuck here. appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns the UTC time, so that explains the 5 hours difference you are getting

You might want to use CONVERT_TZ on the time with a offset of -05.00 (Eastern) to get the right TIMESTAMP.

Comment: is there any reason why it works on my machine but not on the ubuntu one?

Comment: Have you downloaded any timezone tables in mysql recently? Once, you get to mysql prompt, enter `mysql> SET time_zone = '+01:00';` and then run your `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-27 22:15:00');` and see what you get

Comment: no effects on my remote ubuntu machine, but works on my local windows machine.

Comment: this works but still no idea on how it's different on differnt machine with the same setup on timezone.

Comment: well, in addition to the ubuntu having its own system time, MySQL has its own system time. And I think, I am not sure, that when you do select UNIX_TIMESTAMP, it is getting it from the MySQL timezone table.

Comment: When you call MYSQL from PHP, UNIX_TIMESTAMP converts to php timezone.